# Javascript function only continuing after the 'else'

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function getNewMessages(id)
        {
            clearJqGrid();
            var lat;
            var lng;
            var jsonData;
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var miles = $('#milesAway').val();

            // find what the user is locating by
            if ($('#zipCode').is(':visible'))
            {
                var zipText = $('#zipCode').val();
                if (isValidUSZip(zipText))
                {
                    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zipText}, function(results, status) {
                      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                         lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                         lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                      } else {
                        alert("Zip Code couldn't be located.");
                      }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Please enter a valid US zip code.');
                }
            }
            else if ($('#cityState').is(':visible'))
            {
                var address = $('#cityState').val();
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    } else {
                    alert("City/State combination couldn't be found.");
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                var latlng = map.getCenter();
                lat = latlng.lat();
                lng = latlng.lng();
                jsonData = 
                {
                    latitude: lat,
                    longitude: lng,
                    milesAway: miles
                }
            }

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "<%= Url.Action("CalcLocation", "Home") %>",
                data: jsonData,
                success: function (result) {
                    var messages = result;
                    for(var i=0;i<messages.length;i++) 
                        jQuery("#responseMessages").jqGrid(
                                                            'addRowData',
                                                            i+1,
                                                            {distance:messages[i].distance,age:messages[i].age,message:messages[i].message}
                                                          );
                },
                error: function (error) {

                }
            });
        }
```

So it's only making the AJAX call if it goes through the 'else' part of the if statement, not the others. Why?

Comment: Your jsonData assignment is missing a semicolon at the end, but that shouldn't do what you're saying.  Your ajax call's url parameter also doesn't use quotation marks correctly (you need single quotes around the outside or inside, can't use the same type both inside and out).  Does this give you any errors when you load it up in Chrome or Firefox?  Check the error console.

Comment: no errors when i load it up and after the 'else' it runs through fine and works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Milimetric actually got it right, I believe - you're missing the semicolon in your `jsonData` object literal definition. That combined with JavaScript's auto-semi-colon insertion and the way your braces `{}` are written to begin on a new line, is very likely the problem. Put in a semi-colon in there and it should work fine.

In other C-like languages, putting the opening brace on a new line or on the same line is a personal preference but in JavaScript, it does make a difference and so I'd recommend you make a conscious effort to put opening braces on the same line.

- http://encosia.com/2011/03/21/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/
- http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/16/beware-of-javascript-semicolon-insertion/